# Deal with timeout exceptions in an async loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I created a little script that requests my api to fetch information from websites (used as a crawler). I select information from the database and for each result I call my api.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);

query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...";

connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
    async.each(rows, function(row, callback) {
        formattedUrl = "http://localhost:3000/path?url=" + row['url'];
        request({uri: formattedUrl, followAllRedirects: true, method: 'GET'}, function(error, response, body) {
        ...
        callback(null, body);
    }, function(err) {
     //everything is done
    })
})
```

The problem is that too many requests are triggered, so a lot of them end with a timeout exception (the load is too heavy for my api). What should I do to fix that? Is there a way to create a maximum pool of connections (50 for example) as I am able to do with a database?

Comment: So you need a rate limiting queue for those requests.

Comment: I didn't read about the async.forEachLimit function but that could be an option actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Krakig`s comment suggest, you should in fact use async.forEachLimit, like that:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(...);

query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...";

connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
    async.forEachLimit(rows, 50, function(row, callback) {
        formattedUrl = "http://localhost:3000/path?url=" + row['url'];
        request({uri: formattedUrl, followAllRedirects: true, method: 'GET'}, function(error, response, body) {
        ...
        callback(null, body);
    }, function(err) {
     //everything is done
    })
})
```

This will execute 50 parallel requests, and only once a request is done, the next request in line will be executed.

Comment: I also posted a second solution I found and used.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing that :

```
var queue = async.queue(performRequests, 10); // Run 10 simultaneous requests

queue.drain = function() {
    console.log("All requests were performed");
};

connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
    // Queue your data for requests
    queue.push(rows);
});

function performRequests(row, callback) {
    formattedUrl = "http://localhost:3000/path?url=" + row['url'];
    request({uri: formattedUrl, followAllRedirects: true, method: 'GET'}, function(error, response, body) {
        //Do your stuff here
        callback(); //notify request was performed
    })
})
```